# login with LinkedIn: Django REST and React.js

Tags: reactjs, django

I've got problems with authentication with LinkedIn.
In my React app, I created LoginButton component following documentation for react-linkedin-login-oauth2.

```js
import { useLinkedIn } from 'react-linkedin-login-oauth2';
import linkedin from 'react-linkedin-login-oauth2/assets/linkedin.png';


function Login() {
  const { linkedInLogin } = useLinkedIn({
    clientId: '78j5bjwgkxxxxx',
    redirectUri: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/dj-rest-auth/linkedin/',
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      console.log(data)
    },
    onError: (e) => {
      console.log(e)
    }
  });

  return (
    <img
      onClick={linkedInLogin}
      src={linkedin}
    />
  );
}

export default Login
```

That button is kinda working. As far as I'm understanding, 'redirect_URI' should point backend view, it redirects me to http://127.0.0.1:8000/dj-rest-auth/linkedin/ with code and state.
[image]
But backend doesn't log me in automatically and manually (I'm trying to paste "code" form URL to "code" in form below. Then I'm getting that:
[image]
[image]
My backend should work (I did everything following documentation for dj-rest-auth and allauth)

```py
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.linkedin_oauth2.views import LinkedInOAuth2Adapter
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.oauth2.client import OAuth2Client
from dj_rest_auth.registration.views import SocialLoginView


class LinkedinLogin(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = LinkedInOAuth2Adapter
    client_class = OAuth2Client
    callback_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/dj-rest-auth/linkedin/'
```

```py
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('dj-rest-auth/', include('dj_rest_auth.urls')),
    path('dj-rest-auth/registration/', include('dj_rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    path('dj-rest-auth/linkedin/', views.LinkedinLogin.as_view(), name='linkedin_login'),
]
```

Next issue is, after login with button from frontend, I'm getting "user closed the popup" error, I'm not closing or unfocusing anything, in other worlds onError is running, not onSuccess from LoginButton React component.